# Delete/insert failed with Filtered Index on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, filtered-index

I create a stored procedure with default setting like:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

Create  PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP] 
AS
BEGIN
   set arithabort off
   set arithignore on
   --.....
END
```

It is fine. Then I created a filtered unique index on a table for not null value in DB, then I can not run any stored procedure anymore in SQL Server Management Studio. The error I get is something like:

> DELETE(or INSERT) failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

I try to run the stored procedure like:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
EXEC TestSP
```

Or

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
EXEC TestSP
```

I still get above error. I'm very confused. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: what happens if ansi_nulls is set on when you create the stored procedure?

Comment: Why did you create the procedure with those two settings `OFF`? You know that [`SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.90).aspx), right? Stop using it.

Answer (score 2):

The settings for both ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER are based on what those settings are when you create/alter a procedure, not the settings in the instance you run the procedure in.

You want to run an ALTER PROC for your TestSP that sets at least QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to ON when you run it.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP] 

AS
BEGIN
   set arithabort off
   set arithignore on
   --.....
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2c.

I often put `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` *inside* my procs because the messages annoy me and *ocassionally* these warnings incorrectly bubble up through SSIS packages to SQL Agent jobs and incorrectly report a SSIS Package as failed.

I got this error after adding a filtered index. I've now removed the `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`. My proc works now, and I'll see if that SSIS issue was real or not.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be SQL Server issue (inconsistency?). The error "INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: "QUOTED_IDENTIFIER" will be generated if the following conditions are met:

- the table has a column allowing NULLs,  but no default value has been defined, ex:

`[LookupID] [int] NULL`

- there is a unique filtered index defined on this column

  ```
  Create Unique nonclustered index [UniqueExceptNulls] on [tablename]
    ( [lookupID] asc)  where ([LookupID] is not NULL)
  ```

Solution:
add default constraint to column [LookupID]:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] add CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_lookupID] DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [lookupID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this situation and the cause was related to a **file property** and the **deploy** process of my database project on Visual Studio (i.e. *myDatabase.dbproj*).

The root cause of the error is the context where the stored procedure must be created. The database options`ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` must be set **before** the stored procedure is created (setting these options into the sp code is not an error, but it is useless).

The stored procedure would run if I copy-and-paste its source to SQL Server Management Studio, so I was pretty sure the problem was caused by a difference on the `SET` options on deploy context. Then I checked these settings (`Database.sqlsettings`) and everything was ok: `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` were properly set, but the problem still remained...

Until I *found* that each object file has a **Properties** entry on the database project (right click on the file name to show the dialog). These properties were actually overwriting the database settings, so I changed them to `Project Default` and the problem was solved.

[image: sql-file-properies-dialog]

PS: I did more tests creating new stored procedures from Visual Studio and importing manually created ones using the Schema Comparison and the files are created with the `Project Default`, so I think that this setting was changed manually or wrongly imported from a previous version of Visual Studio.